# What does AOT instrumentation mean?

Tags: java, bytecode, instrumentation, jvm-bytecode, quasar

I know what bytecode instrumentation is. It is simply changing .class files bytecodes during runtime, which seems to be available since JDK 1.5. However, it's said to be during class loading not exactly runtime.
Now my question is, what is AOT or Ahead of Time instrumentation? What is the opposite procedure? Over Time Instrumentation?

> **Instrumenting Your Code**
>  Quasar fibers rely on bytecode
>   instrumentation. This can be done at classloading time via a `Java Agent`,
>   or at compilation time with an Ant task.
>
> **Running the Instrumentation**
>  Java Agent `Quasar`’s lightweight thread
>   implementation relies on bytecode instrumentation. Instrumentation can
>   be performed at compilation time (detailed below) or at runtime using
>   a Java agent. To run the Java agent, the following must be added to
>   the java command line (or use your favorite build tool to add this as
>   a JVM argument):
>
> `-javaagent:path-to-quasar-jar.jar`
>   **Ahead-of-Time (AOT) Instrumentation**
>   The easy and preferable way to instrument programs using Quasar is
>   with the Java agent, which instruments code at runtime. Sometimes,
>   however, running a Java agent is not an option.
>
> Quasar supports AOT instrumentation with an Ant task. The task is
>   `co.paralleluniverse.fibers.instrument.InstrumentationTask` found in
>   `quasar-core.jar`, and it accepts a fileset of classes to instrument.
>   Not all classes will actually be instrumented – only those with
>   `suspendable method`s (see below) – so simply give the task all of the
>   class files in your program. In fact, Quasar itself is instrumented
>   **ahead-of-time**.

[Source](http://docs.paralleluniverse.co/quasar/#instrumentation)

Comment: Do you have any reference? I would say, `Ahead of Time instrumentation` is an instrumentation mechanism where the instrumentation takes place before the code is executed (and the instrumented code is stored so that it can be executed later without being re-instrumented), and the opposite would be `Just in Time instrumentation` where the code is instrumented **each time** directly before the code is executed. See also [Ahead of time **compilation**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ahead-of-time_compilation) and [Just in time **compilation**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ahead-of-time (AOT) compilation/instrumentation is just that, it takes place before running the program.

The opposite of AOT is Just-in-time, or JIT. It happens during runtime. In Java, class loading is done *at runtime*, and there are mechanics to fiddle with it.

In your example, AOT instrumentation is done via an Ant task before running the program, and the changes are written into the `.class` file.

The other possible way is doing it JIT, with a Java Agent. in this case, the instrumentation takes place at runtime when the class is loaded, and the result is not written into the file, but instead must be done anew every time the class is loaded.

See [Wikipedia/Ahead-of-time-compilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ahead-of-time_compilation) and [Wikipedia/Just-in-time-compilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation) for more info.

Comment: Instrumentation and JIT optimization are different things.

Comment: @Polygnome No it seems to be different. Please see my updated question.

Comment: It seems to be exactly that. Qasar can either do it AOT using an Ant task or JIT using a Java Agent... but I made my answer more precise to better match your updated question

Comment: Thanks for editing your answer. Now I can accept it.